# App.run initiate twice in angular/ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am experiencing an weird issue in my ionic app. The `app.run` seems to be execute twice as when i `console.log('message')` the log message appears twice. Anyone experiencing the same weird issue?

I am using ionic v1.3.0 which is using angular 1.5.x

Comment: Please add your code to here for more details

Comment: Make sure you are not adding angular twice, since Ionic.bundle already includes built-in angular implementation.